# Crasheo después de cargar datos de un archivo binario en un vector

Tags: c++

Tengo un problemilla con un ejercicio de una (proto)base de datos de empleados, que consiste en crear una aplicación de consola para almacenar datos introducidos por el usuario en un vector de elementos de una clase "Empleado". Dicha clase es abstracta y de ella heredan otras tres llamadas "Jefe", "Ingeniero" e "Investigador" y todas ellas son muy simples, tienen como miembros arrays de caracteres únicamente para almacenar los datos (nombre, salario, experiencia...).

Cuando digo que son simples me refiero a que no hay punteros ni vectores ni nada complejo dentro de ellas. El programa debe tener la opción de guardar los datos en un fichero binario y poder cargar dichos datos de vuelta al volver a ejecutar el programa.

Todo funciona correctamente, pero al intentar visualizar los datos una vez cargados del fichero binario el programa "casca" y no entiendo por qué.

Esta es la clase padre 'Empleado' :

```
class Empleado
{
    public:
        virtual ~Empleado() {} ;

        virtual void MostrarDatos() = 0;

    protected:
        char mTipoEmpleado[16];
        char mNombre[100];
        char mApellido[100];
        float mSalario;

    private:
};
```

Esta es una de las clases que heredan de Empleado, en este caso es la clase 'Jefe' :

```
class Jefe : public Empleado
{
    public:

        Jefe();
        Jefe(char Nombre[], char Apellido[], float Salario, unsigned int reunionesSemanales, unsigned int diasVacacionesAnuales);

        virtual ~Jefe() {}

        void MostrarDatos();

    protected:
        unsigned int mReunionesSemanales;
        unsigned int mDiasVacacionesAnuales;

    private:

};
```

Esta es la función Main:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    cout << endl << " ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////" << endl;
    cout << " // BIENVENIDO AL GESTOR DE LA BASE DE DATOS DE EMPLEADOS //" << endl;
    cout << " //                                          //" << endl;
    cout << " ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////" << endl;

    int eleccion = 0;
    bool salir = false;
    vector<Empleado*> empleados;

    while (!salir)
    {
        cout << endl << " Escoge una opcion por favor : " << endl;
        cout << endl << " 1.- Agregar empleado" << endl;
        cout << " 2.- Eliminar empleado" << endl;
        cout << " 3.- Guardar base de datos" << endl;
        cout << " 4.- Cargar base de datos" << endl;
        cout << " 5.- Mostrar base de datos" << endl;
        cout << " 6.- Salir" << endl;
        cout << " Opcion : ";
        cin >> eleccion;

        switch (eleccion)
        {
        case 1:
        {
            system("cls");
            bool salirTipoEmpleado = false;
            int tipoEmpleado = 0;

            while (!salirTipoEmpleado)
            {
                cout << endl << " Escoge tipo de empleado por favor : " << "\n";
                cout << endl << " 1.- Jefe" << "\n";
                cout << " 2.- Ingeniero" << "\n";
                cout << " 3.- Investigador" << "\n";
                cout << " 4.- Volver" << "\n";
                cout << " Opcion : ";
                cin >> tipoEmpleado;

                switch (tipoEmpleado)
                {
                case 1:
                {
                    empleados.push_back(new Jefe);
                    system("cls");
                    cout << " Nuevo Jefe incluido con exito en la base de datos." << "\n";
                }
                break;
                case 2:
                {
                    empleados.push_back(new Ingeniero);
                    system("cls");
                    cout << " Nuevo Ingeniero incluido con exito en la base de datos." << "\n";
                }
                break;
                case 3:
                {
                    empleados.push_back(new Investigador);
                    system("cls");
                    cout << " Nuevo Investigador incluido con exito en la base de datos." << "\n";
                }
                break;
                case 4:
                    salirTipoEmpleado = true;
                    break;
                    system("cls");
                } // Fin switch
            } // Fin while(!salirTipo...)
        } // Fin case 1
        break;
        case 2:
        {
            system("cls");
            if (empleados.size() == 0)
                cout << " Base de datos vacia." << "\n";
            else
            {
                unsigned int indice = -1;
                while (indice < 0 || indice >= empleados.size())
                {
                    cout << " La base de datos tiene " << empleados.size() << " empleados." << "\n";
                    cout << " Elige empleado a borrar (primer empleado es el numero 0) : ";
                    cin >> indice;
                    if (indice < 0 || indice >= empleados.size()) cout << " Fuera de rango." << "\n";

                    else
                    {
                        empleados.erase(empleados.begin() + indice);
                        cout << " Empleado " << indice << " borrado." << "\n";
                        indice = 0;
                        if (empleados.size() == 0) break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        break;
        case 3:
        {
            ofstream guardarDatos("Base_datos_Empleados.dat", ios::binary);
            GuardarDatosBinario("Base_datos_Empleados.dat", empleados);

            if (guardarDatos.good()) cout << " Base de datos guardada correctamente." << "\n";
            else cout << " Error al guardar Base de datos." << "\n";
        }
        break;
        case 4:
        {
            ifstream cargarDatos("Base_datos_Empleados.dat", ios::in | ios::binary | ios::ate);
            if (cargarDatos.is_open())
            {
                empleados = LeerArchivoBinario("Base_datos_Empleados.dat");
            }
            else cout << " Error al cargar datos." << "\n";
        }
        break;
        case 5:
        {
            system("cls");
            if (empleados.size() == 0)
            {
                cout << " Base de datos vacia.";
                break;
            }
            else cout << " La base de datos tiene " << empleados.size() << " empleados. " << "\n";
            for (Empleado* emp : empleados)
            {
                emp->MostrarDatos();
                cout << endl;
            }
        }
        break;
        case 6:
        {
            empleados.erase(empleados.begin(), empleados.end());
            if (empleados.size() == 0)
                cout << " Base de datos borrada. " << "\n";
            else cout << " Fallo al borrar la base de datos. " << " \n";        
        } // Fin case 5
        salir = true;
        break;
        } // Fin switch(eleccion)
    } // Fin while(!salir)

    return 0;
}
```

Esta es la función que guarda los datos en un fichero binario. Toma como argumentos un nombre de archivo y un vector de punteros a 'Empleado':

```
void GuardarDatosBinario(const char* archivoBinario, const vector<Empleado*> empleados)
{
    ofstream guardarDatos(archivoBinario, ios::binary);
    for (const Empleado* emp : empleados)
        guardarDatos.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&emp), sizeof(emp));
}
```

Y esta es la que carga los datos del archivo binario en el vector de punteros a Empleados :

```
vector<Empleado*> LeerArchivoBinario(const char* archivoBinario)
{
    vector<Empleado*> temporal;
    ifstream cargarDatos(archivoBinario, ios::binary);
    Empleado* empleadoTemp;
    while (cargarDatos.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&empleadoTemp),sizeof(empleadoTemp)))
        temporal.push_back(empleadoTemp);

    return temporal;    
}
```

Aparentemente los datos se cargan porque esta línea

```
cout << " La base de datos tiene " << empleados.size() << " empleados. " << "\n";
```

incluida justo antes del bucle para visualizar los datos del vector de punteros 'Empleado' responde el número correcto (2, 3, 7, 10...) pero inmediatamente después al empezar a recorrer el vector aparece la temida "segmentation fault".

Este es el bucle

```
for (Empleado* emp : empleados)
{
    emp->MostrarDatos(); //-----> AQUÍ APARECE EL ERROR.
    cout << endl;
}
```

Y ésta es la función para visualizar los datos, en este caso de la clase 'Jefe' pero las otras son iguales:

```
void Jefe::MostrarDatos()
{
    std::cout << " Tipo empleado : " << mTipoEmpleado << "\n";
    std::cout << " Nombre   : " << mNombre << "\n";
    std::cout << " Apellido : " << mApellido << "\n";
    std::cout << " Salario  : " << mSalario << "\n";

    std::cout << " Reuniones Semanales : " << mReunionesSemanales << "\n";
    std::cout << " Dias de vacaciones anuales : " << mDiasVacacionesAnuales << "\n";
}
```

En fin que no entiendo por qué no funciona. Me pregunto si tendrá algo que ver que al ser 'Empleado' una clase abstracta no se pueda 'grabar' tan fácilmente en un fichero binario debido a la 'vtable' y que haya que usar serialización o algo por el estilo, que de momento es ciencia-ficción para mí.

Cualquier orientación al respecto es más que bienvenida.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
void GuardarDatosBinario(const char* archivoBinario, const vector<Empleado*> empleados)
{
    ofstream guardarDatos(archivoBinario, ios::binary);
    for (const Empleado* emp : empleados)
        guardarDatos.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&emp), sizeof(emp));
}
```

Un detalle tonto del código anterior es que conviene evitar pasar objetos grandes por valor, ya que ello implica realizar una copia del mismo. En su caso es suele ser conveniente usar una referencia constante:

```
void GuardarDatosBinario(const char* archivoBinario, const vector<Empleado*>& empleados)
//                                                                          ^
{
    ofstream guardarDatos(archivoBinario, ios::binary);
    for (const Empleado* emp : empleados)
        guardarDatos.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&emp), sizeof(emp));
}
```

En cualquier caso ese método no va a funcior porque `emp` es un puntero, por lo que `&emp` es un puntero doble y `sizeof(emp)` te va a devolver el tamaño de un puntero (4 bytes en 32bits y 8 bytes en 64). Lo que está haciendo el programa en este punto es, básicamente, almacenar en el fichero la dirección de memoria donde se encuentra el objeto actualmente... pero ten por seguro que no va a encontrar ahí la próxima vez que leas el fichero. Para almacenar los datos tendrías que almacenar la memoria apuntada por `emp`... pero como estás a punto de descubrir te va a dar nuevos problemas. De momento podemos asumir que dejas la función así:

```
void GuardarDatosBinario(const char* archivoBinario, const vector<Empleado*>& empleados)
{
    ofstream guardarDatos(archivoBinario, ios::binary);
    for (const Empleado* emp : empleados)
        guardarDatos.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(emp), sizeof(*emp));
}
```

Para explicar uno de los problemas de esta nueva versión de la función,  fíjate en el siguiente ejemplo:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  std::cout << sizeof(Empleado);
}
```

¿Qué valor dirías que va a imprimir el programa?

Un vistazo rápido nos diría que: 16 Bytes (`mTipoEmpleado`) + 100 Bytes (`mNombre`) + 100 Bytes (`mApellido`) + 4 Bytes (`mSalario`) = 220 Bytes

Pero si ejecuto el código anterior el programa imprime lo siguiente:

```
224
```

¿De dónde salen esos 4 bytes extra? Esos 4 Bytes de más los ocupa un puntero interno de la clase que apunta a una estructura que se usa para gestionar las llamadas virtuales y el polimorfismo (conocida como `vtable`). No parece muy sensato escribir esa dirección de memoria en el fichero porque cuando pretendas recuperar la información del fichero ese puntero dejará de ser válido y el programa te dará errores extraños.

Otro problema de esta función es que `sizeof` no es capaz de leer la `vtable`, por lo que no sabe si el puntero es de un objeto de tipo `Jefe` (por poner un ejemplo) y, en consecuencia, **siempre** devolverá el tamaño de la clase `Empleado`. El efecto conseguido es que únicamente se almacenará la información propia de la clase base, perdiéndose el resto.

El tercer problema que tiene esta función es que si en el futuro te da por cambiar, por ejemplo, `char mNombre[100]` por `string mNombre`, te va a ser imposible tanto recuperar datos antiguos como guardar los nuevos. `std::string` así como otras tantas clases suelen hacer uso de memoria dinámica y eso hará que en el fichero almacenes direcciones de memoria en vez de datos válidos.

Debido a la naturaleza de las cases en C++, para serializar información en un fichero lo más recomendable suele ser escribir los datos de forma explícita:

```
void GuardarDatosBinario(const char* archivoBinario, const vector<Empleado*> empleados)
{
    ofstream guardarDatos(archivoBinario, ios::binary);
    for (const Empleado* emp : empleados)
    {
        guardarDatos.write(emp->mTipoEmpleado,sizeof(emp->mTipoEmpleado));
        guardarDatos.write(emp->mNombre,sizeof(emp->mNombre));
        guardarDatos.write(emp->mApellido,sizeof(emp->mApellido));
        guardarDatos.write((char*)&emp->mSalario,sizeof(emp->mSalario));
    }
}
```

Date cuenta de que para poder acceder a los miembros de la clase tendrás que declararlos como `public` o declarar la función como `friend` de `Empleado`. También puedes crear un juego de `getters` para proporcionar acceso a los datos.

Fíjate que aun así llegados a este punto únicamente estás guardando los datos de la clase base. ¿Cómo se deberían guardar los de las clases derivadas? Podrías hacer que la función fuese capaz de reconocer cada uno de los objetos, pero no es recomendable porque la función empezará a ser complicada de gestionar:

```
void GuardarDatosBinario(const char* archivoBinario, const vector<Empleado*> empleados)
{
    ofstream guardarDatos(archivoBinario, ios::binary);
    for (const Empleado* emp : empleados)
    {
        guardarDatos.write(emp->mTipoEmpleado,sizeof(emp->mTipoEmpleado));
        guardarDatos.write(emp->mNombre,sizeof(emp->mNombre));
        guardarDatos.write(emp->mApellido,sizeof(emp->mApellido));
        guardarDatos.write((char*)&emp->mSalario,sizeof(float));

        if( Jeje* jefe = dynamic_cast<Jefe*>(emp) )
        {
            guardarDatos.write((char*)emp->mReunionesSemanales,sizeof(int));
            // ...
        }
        else if( // ...

    }
}
```

Otra posibilidad sería que cada objeto supiese guardarse a sí mismo (con una función virtual), pero no se si esta solución es válida para tu ejercicio pues ignoro las restricciones.

Bueno, ya está el guardado finiquitado, ¿verdad? Pues no. ¿Qué falta? vamos a verlo desde la perspectiva de la lectura. Intentamos leer el primer registro del fichero( `mTipoEmpleado`, `mNombre`, `mApellido`, `mSalario` ) y ahora nos encontramos más información... ¿Es un nuevo registro? ¿Son datos de un objeto de tipo `Jefe`? ¿o será información de un objeto de tipo `Ingeniero`? No solo no tienes información como para saber qué decisión tomar sino que además la decisión tendrías que haberla tomado antes: Deberías saber qué tipo de objeto tienes que crear antes de empezar a leer los datos del registro).

Lo que falta en el fichero es una marca o identificación que te permita saber qué tipo de registro vas a leer. Esta marca podría ser un simple enumerado:

```
enum TipoEmpleado
{
  Indefinido,
  Jefe,
  Ingeniero,
  Investigador,
};
```

Entonces el guardado podría quedar así (por limpieza he dividido la función):

```
void Write(std::ofstream& out, int valor)
{
  out.write((char*)&valor,sizeof(int));
}

void Write(std::ofstream& out, float valor)
{
  out.write((char*)&valor,sizeof(float));
}

void GuardarDatosEmpleado(std::ofstream& out, const Empleado& emp)
{
    guardarDatos.write(emp.mTipoEmpleado,sizeof(emp.mTipoEmpleado));
    guardarDatos.write(emp.mNombre,sizeof(emp.mNombre));
    guardarDatos.write(emp.mApellido,sizeof(emp.mApellido));
    Write(guardarDatos,emp.mSalario);
}

void GuardarDatosBinario(const char* archivoBinario, const vector<Empleado*> empleados)
{
    ofstream guardarDatos(archivoBinario, ios::binary);
    for (const Empleado* emp : empleados)
    {
        if( Jeje* jefe = dynamic_cast<Jefe*>(emp) )
        {
            Write(guardarDatos,TipoEmpleado::Jefe);
            GuardarDatosEmpleado(*emp);
            Write(guardarDatos,jefe->mReunionesSemanales);
            Write(guardarDatos,jefe->mDiasVacacionesAnuales);
        }
        else if( Ingeniero* ingeniero = dynamic_cast<Ingeniero*>(emp) )
        {
            Write(guardarDatos,TipoEmpleado::Ingeniero);
            GuardarDatosEmpleado(*emp);
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

Repasemos ahora la función de lectura:

```
vector<Empleado*> LeerArchivoBinario(const char* archivoBinario)
{
    vector<Empleado*> temporal;
    ifstream cargarDatos(archivoBinario, ios::binary);
    Empleado* empleadoTemp;
    while (cargarDatos.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&empleadoTemp),sizeof(empleadoTemp)))
        temporal.push_back(empleadoTemp);

    return temporal;    
}
```

Fíjate en esta línea:

```
Empleado* empleadoTemp;
```

Declaras un puntero pero no reservas memoria para el mismo, luego va a apuntar a una posición aleatoria y al Sistema Operativo no le suele gustar que accedas a memoria que no te corresponde.

Aquí tendrás que crear un objeto de tipo `Jefe`, `Ingeniero` o `Investigador`. ¿Cómo hacerlo? Parte del problema ya lo hemos solucionado al revisar el guardado. El entero que precede al registro nos va a decir qué tipo de objeto se está almacenando a continuación:

```
Empleado* empleadoTemp = 0; // Es importante inicializar los punteros
TipoEmpleado tipo;
cargarDatos.Read((char*)&tipo,sizeof(int));

switch( tipo )
{
  case TipoEmpleado::Jefe:
    empleadoTemp = new Jefe;
    // Rutina para leer un registro de tipo Jefe
    break;

  case TipoEmpleado::Ingeniero:
    empleadoTemp = new Ingeniero;
    // Rutina para leer un registro de tipo Ingeniero
    break;
}
```

Y, por supuesto, eliminamos la línea:

```
while (cargarDatos.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&empleadoTemp),sizeof(empleadoTemp)))
```

Ten en cuenta que ahora tendrás que leer cada variable de forma individual, algo similar a lo que has visto en la escritura:

```
cargarDatos.read(empleadoTemp->mTipoEmpleado,sizeof(empleadoTemp->mTipoEmpleado));
```

---

> Respecto a que cada objeto supiese guardarse a sí mismo con una función virtual, era algo que pensé en un primer momento pero descarté porque me parecía que duplicaría mucho código...

Si sobreescribes una función en una clase derivada puedes forzar llamadas a la función de la clase padre para reutilizar su código:

```
struct A
{
  virtual void func()
  { std::cout << "A::func()" << std::endl; }
};

struct B : A
{
  void func()
  {
    std::cout << "B::func()" << std::endl;
    A::func();
 }
};

int main()
{
  B b;
  b.func();
}
```

Esta llamada la puedes realizar en cualquier parte, aunque lo habitual es encontrarla al principio o al final de la función derivada.

En tu caso en concreto el proceso de guardado se podría realizar facilmente sin duplicar código:

```
class Empleado
{
  public:

    virtual void Guardar(std::ofstream& out)
    {
      guardarDatos.write(mTipoEmpleado,sizeof(mTipoEmpleado));
      guardarDatos.write(mNombre,sizeof(mNombre));
      guardarDatos.write(mApellido,sizeof(mApellido));
      Write(guardarDatos,mSalario);
    }
};

class Jefe : public Empleado
{
  void Guardar(std::ofstream& out)
  {
    Write(guardarDatos,TipoEmpleado::Jefe);

    Empleado::Guardar(out);

    Write(guardarDatos,jefe->mReunionesSemanales);
    Write(guardarDatos,jefe->mDiasVacacionesAnuales);
  }
};
```

Comment: Ya me parecía que no iba a ser tan fácil y que la 'vtable' tenía algo que ver en el problema.

Comment: @Battyhal si esta pregunta resuelve su problema seria recomendado que la acepte, haciendo check en la parte izquierda donde estan la flechas de votar, veo que has leido el "recorrido", por lo que estaras al tanto de la utilidad de eso. Saludos y bienvenido a StackOveflow.

Comment: Hecho. Estaba escribiendo una respuesta pero se me ha pasado el tiempo. Pido disculpas.

Comment: @eferion Y gracias por el apunte de que es mejor pasar objetos grandes por referencia. Respecto a que cada objeto supiese guardarse a sí mismo con una función virtual, era algo que pensé en un primer momento pero descarté porque me parecía que duplicaría mucho código y por eso me centré en la clase base 'Empleado' y en una función 'general' que sirviera para todo. Ahora veo lo equivocado que estaba.

Comment: @eferion hay algo que no me queda claro y es el porqué de la función 'Write' (void Write(std::ofstream& out, int valor)). ¿No se puede guardar el valor de 'mSalario' (por ejemplo) utilizando la función write 'normal' (me refiero a std::ofstream::write) ?.

Comment: @Battyhal sí se podría, pero en la forma en la que lo he puesto lo guardas en binario... si usas `write(mSalario)` vas a guardar el dato en formato texto y no es lo que pretendes... la versión de `Write` es un _syntactic sugar_ para no reescribir ese código todo el rato.

Comment: @eferion Es verdad, que tonto soy. Muchas gracias eferion.

Comment: @Battyhal tonto no. C++ es muy complejo y es dificil estar pendiente de todo a la vez... por ese motivo hay portales como este. :)

Comment: @Battyhal *Hecho. Estaba escribiendo una respuesta pero se me ha pasado el tiempo...* No problem, lo importante es que la marcaste ahora, muchos nunca la marcan, sin saber lo perjudicial que es eso, por no mencionar lo poco justo que es para el autor de la respuesta (que en este caso no es una respuesta corta) ademas como usuario nuevo es entendible que se te pasara, pero ante todo no pienses que te estoy recriminando algo de mala manera. Saludos

Comment: @Battyhal revisa la respuesta que he añadido información que creo que te interesa

Comment: @ eferion Este añadido me hace ratificar lo que dije antes : 'ahora veo lo equivocado que estaba' ;).

Comment: @ Angel Angel Ni mucho menos me lo he tomado a mal ni me ha parecido que me recriminaras. Todo lo contrario, me gusta que me lo digas porque soy de los que piensa que hay muy malas formas por los foros y portales del vasto Internet y cuando algo no se ha hecho bien hay que corregirlo. A tenor de esto me gustaría preguntar si cuando reescriba el código lo puedo postear aquí para dejarlo disponible para el que le venga bien o eso no está permitido.

Comment: Bueno, si consigo hacerlo que igual estoy hablando muy rápido...