# Problemas archivos .bin en C++

Tags: c++

Quiero hacer un programa tipo agenda en el que pueda guardar mis contactos en un archivo .bin. El problema es que cuando corro el programa crashea.

Esta es la parte que lee el .bin:

```
ifstream entrada;
    entrada.open(Archivo,ios::binary);
    Contacto c;
    while(entrada.read((char*)&c,sizeof(Contacto))){
        c.Print();
    }

    entrada.close();
```

Donde `Archivo` es una constante que guarda el nombre del archivo: `contactos.dat`

Comment: La extensión del archivo es irrelevante. Necesitamos conocer más detalles del objeto `Contacto`.

Answer (score 0):

```
while(entrada.read((char*)&c,sizeof(Contacto)))
//                 ^^^^^^^^^
```

Si `Contacto` resulta que usa, de forma directa o indirecta, memoria dinámica esa lectura te va a fallar. ¿por qué? Porque entonces asi vas a copiar punteros en vez de los valores que te interesan.

Un ejemplo:

```
class Prueba {
  int* datos;
};

int main ()
{
  std::cout << sizeof(Prueba);
}
```

El siguiente programa imprimira 4 u 8 dependiendo de si lo compilas en 32 bits o en 64... independientemente de lo que haya almacenado en `datos`.

Si tu coges y vuelcas `Prueba` a un fichero asi a lo bruto lo que vas a hacer es guardar únicamente el valor del puntero... así si `datos` apunta a una lista de 20 elementos ubicada en `0x102030`, en el fichero se almacenara 0x102030. Nota que los datos no se estan guardando, luego al cerrar el programa los datos se perderán para siempre...

¿y por qué  casca el programa?

Porque estas sobreescribiendo los punteros haciendo que los mismos apunten a posiciones no válidas.

Si, en el ejemplo anterior, lees el fichero y guardas su contenido en un objeto de tipo `Prueba`, lo que conseguirás es que `datos` apunte a `0x102030`... es facil adivinar que esa memoria no le pertenece a tu aplicación,  por lo que el sistema operativo se protege y mata tu aplicación con el único fin de evitar que corrompa la memoria.

Lo que tienes que hacer es guardar los miembros de tu objeto de forma  manual... uno a uno... el mecanismo que describes solo es válido si evitas la memoria dinámica:

```
struct Funciona
{
  int var1;
  char var2 [100];
};

struct NoFunciona
{
  int var1;
  char *var2; // un puntero!!!!
  std::string var3; // string usa internamente punteros!!!
};
```

Como no has puesto la declaración de `Contacto` es imposible darte mas información

Comment: Osea, lo que me sugieres que haga es que no use strings, pero arrays de chars?

Comment: @ChinoPicnik de.ninguna manera... es mejor usar  string porque es mucho mas flexible... pero requiere trabajar de otra forma

Comment: De que manera podría trabajarlo? Las restricciones que tengo para este proyecto es que utilice clases  y los atributos sean privados (Por ende usar getters y setters). He estado intentando trabajarlo con char [], pero tengo problemas al retornarlo y siento que estaría usando punteros otra vez. Que me recomendaría para resolver mi problema?

Comment: @ChinoPicnik echa un vistazo a [este enlace](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/50413/crasheo-despu%c3%a9s-de-cargar-datos-de-un-archivo-binario-en-un-vector)