# ¿Como puedo instanciar desde una clase un objeto de otra, considerando que debo hacer eso con mas de una clase? c++

Tags: c++, archivo, clase

Debo hacer un programa que utilice por lo menos 12 clases, las cuales son una jerarquía de una librería, por lo que cada genero de literario tendrá su propia clase con sus atributos, lo que busco hacer es que la clase Librería pueda registrar un libro  usando los atributos de las clases de los géneros.
La clase Librería es la siguiente:

```
    class Libreria{
    public:
        Libreria();
        void mostrarLibros();
        void agregarLibro(/*Aqui quiero que pueda recibir un objeto x que sirva para tomar los atributos de la clase que se quiera usar, no solo de un genero*/Terror&);
        void buscarLibro();
        void eliminarLibro();
};

Libreria::Libreria(){
}

void Libreria::agregarLibro(Terror &libro){
    int opc;
    ofstream registrar;
    cout << "Seleccione la seccion: " << endl;
    cout << "1.Literarios" << endl;
    cout << "2.Cientificos" << endl;
    cout << "0.Salir" << endl;
    cin >> opc;
    do{
        switch(opc){
            case 1:{
                do{
                cout << "Seleccione un genero: " << endl;
                cout << "1.Terror" << endl;
                cout << "2.Romantica" << endl;
                cout << "3.Comedia" << endl;
                cout << "4.Drama" << endl;
                cout << "5.Suspenso" << endl;
                cin >> opc;
                    switch(opc){
                        case 1:{
                            //Para que pueda registrarlo en un archivo
                            registrar.open("terror.txt", ios::app);
                            cout << "Titulo: ";
                            cin >> libro.nombre;
                            cout << "Autor: ";
                            cin >> libro.autor;
                            cout << "Editorial: ";
                            cin >> libro.editorial;
                            cout << "Precio: ";
                            cin >> libro.precio;
                            cout << "Id: ";
                            cin >> libro.idSec;

                            registrar << libro.nombre << "\n" << libro.autor << "\n" << libro.precio << "\n" << libro.idSec << endl;

                            cout << "Libro registrado" << endl;
                            registrar.close();
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }while(opc != 0);
                break;
            }
        }
    }while(opc!=0);
}
```

Una de las clases de un genero seria así:

```
class Terror : public Novela{
    private:
        int idLibro;
    public:
        Terror(char*, char*, char*, double, int, int);
        friend class Libreria;
};

Terror::Terror(char *_nom, char *_aut, char *_edit, double _pre, int _idSeccion, int idLib) : Novela(_nom, _aut, _edit, _pre, _idSeccion){
    idLibro = idLib;
}
```

Lo intente usando amistad entre clases, pero el detalle con ello es que tendría que crear un método por cada genero, así que quería saber si hay una forma de que pueda recibir un objeto de cualquiera de las clases de géneros, para poder registrar un libro según sus propios atributos o alguna otra forma de solucionarlo.

Comment: Cuando dices *"Se llame a esa clase ..."* ¿A qué clase te refieres? ¿a una clase `Genero`? ¿tal vez a una clase `Libro`? ¿Otra cosa? ¿Existen las clases que pretendes usar? ¿Qué interfaz tienen o deben tener? Te sugiero reformular tu pregunta para que el objetivo de la misma quede claro.

Comment: Tienes razón, gracias por la sugerencia. A lo que me refiero es que cada case, que hace referencia a un género tiene una clase correspondiente, lo que quiero hacer es que el método registarLibro que es de una clase librería tome los atributos de esa clase para hacer el registro y guardarlo en un archivo, pensé en hacerlo con clases amigas, pero en ese caso solo lo pude hacer con una sola clase, ya que como parámetro recibiría un objeto de el género correspondiente

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta y añade la información que falta. Si fuerzas a que la gente tenga que leerse los comentarios para poder responder vas a recibir muy poquita atención

Comment: En cualquier caso, lo que has comentado sigue siendo insuficiente. No has puesto nada sobre esas otras clases de las que hablas por lo que es complicado hacerse una idea sobre cómo funcionan

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Para agregar informacion a tu pregunta podes usar el boton [edit] trata de evitar agregar demasiada informacion en comentarios. Los mismos se usan solamente para aclaraciones puntuales.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si te he entendido bien, tu intención es usar esas clases para registrar los diferentes libros. Puedes tratar el tema de forma genérica usando una factoría.

Lo primero que hay que hacer es declarar un enumerado con los diferentes tipos de objetos a crear:

```
enum class Genero
{
  SinGenero,    // 0, se puede usar para variables no inicializadas
  Terror,       // 1
  Romantica,    // 2
  Comedia,      // 3
  Drama,        // 4
  Suspense,     // 5
  // ...
};
```

A continuación usamos la factoría para que nos devuelva un objeto del género que corresponda:

```
namespace FactoriaLibros
{
  Libro* NuevoLibro(Genero genero)
  {
    Libro* toReturn = nullptr;
    switch( genero )
    {
      case Genero::Terror:
        toReturn = new Terror;
        break;

      case Genero::Romantica:
        toReturn = new Romantica;
        break;

      // ...
    }

    return toReturn;
  }
};
```

Ahora ya podemos crear objetos de forma genérica usando esta factoría:

```
do{
  cout << "Seleccione un genero: \n"
       << "1.Terror\n"
       << "2.Romantica\n"
       << "3.Comedia\n"
       << "4.Drama\n"
       << "5.Suspenso\n";
  cin >> opc;

  Libro* libro = FactoriaLibros::NuevoLibro(static_cast<Genero>(opc));
```

Nota que en este punto es importante que las opciones del menú estén correctamente alineadas con los valores del enumerado. Y bueno, ahora queda otro punto aparentemente complicado... ¿cómo rellenamos el objeto `libro` si no sabemos de qué tipo es?

Aquí podemos usar funciones virtuales. Por ejemplo podemos implementar una función `Leer`:

```
class Libro
{
public:

  virtual void Read(std::istream & is)
  {
    is >> titulo >> autor;
  }

private:
  std::string titulo;
  std::string autor;   
};

class Terror : public Libro
{
  void Read(std::istream & is) override
  {
    Libro::Read(is); // llamamos primero a la función de la clase padre

    is >> idLibro;
  }

private:
  int idLibro;
};
```

Y para que el uso sea un poco más natural, creamos una sobrecarga del operador de extracción:

```
std::istream& operator>>( std::istream& in, Libro & libro)
{
  libro.Read(in);

  return in;
}
```

Con todo esto la lectura de los libros es trivial:

```
Libro* libro = FactoriaLibros::NuevoLibro(static_cast<Genero>(opc));
std::cin >> *libro; // Pedimos al usuario los datos del libro
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, es justamente lo que necesitaba, el único problema que estoy teniendo es en los case, ya que me indica que en todas las expresiones de tipo "Genero::Terror" me dice que ninguno, tanto Genero como Terror, no son una clase o un namespace. Agradecería mucho tu ayuda

Comment: @FernandoHernandez eso es porque no tienes activado el estándar C++11. Para compilar con algún estándar anterior (C++98), quita el `class` al declarar el `enum` y después quita `Genero::` en los `case`

Comment: Ahora me marca que en el toReturn, Terror no nombra a un tipo

Comment: @FernandoHernandez ah claro, te está colisionando `Terror` como valor del enumerado y como clase que hereda de `Libro`... renombra uno de los dos para evitar la colisión

Comment: Ya funciona! pero hay otro detalle, si quiero pasar ese objeto que se creo, a un fichero, como lo haría?, porque a como lo estoy haciendo pasa basura al fichero

Comment: @FernandoHernandez Revisa [este enlace](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/50449/463)